Paho Mqtt in Unreal Engine 5.3.2
I'm trying to create a plugin for Unreal Engine 5.3.2 for connecting to an mqtt broker in c++ and for that I need to use paho.mqtt.c and paho.mqtt.cpp. I built the 2 libraries with cmake. When I tried to run my c++ in vs code everything was compiled successfully and the result was the expected but when I tried with the same code in visual studio 2022 I'm getting the linker errors below:

Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter DigitalTwin C:\Users\chrre\OneDrive\Desktop\DigitalTwin\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\paho-mqttpp3-static.lib(async_client.obj) 1
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReport  DigitalTwin C:\Users\chrre\OneDrive\Desktop\DigitalTwin\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\paho-mqttpp3-static.lib(ssl_options.obj)  1
Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in SharedPCH.Engine.Cpp20.h.obj    DigitalTwin C:\Users\chrre\OneDrive\Desktop\DigitalTwin\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\paho-mqttpp3-static.lib(create_options.obj)   1
Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in SharedPCH.Engine.Cpp20.h.obj    DigitalTwin C:\Users\chrre\OneDrive\Desktop\DigitalTwin\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\paho-mqttpp3-static.lib(disconnect_options.obj)   1

I tried every solution possible so far and nothing is working. A lot of solutions recommended to add the libraries to the linker through the solution properties in visual studio but I don't have any linker or C/C++ section in my solution properties. I also added the libraries and the header files both in the Build.cs file as well as in the general configuration in the solution properties. I even tried to import the files with "" and not with <>! :( I tried then windows sdk and to import some libraries myself but this didn't work as well. I don't know what else to try! Does anyone successfully managed to import those 2 libraries and can provide me with a step by step guide?
